# Distributing points on boundary (roughly) evenly

Tags: graphics, mesh

How to get roughly evenly distributed mesh points along boundary?

We can see marked by red circles, that some points are too close to each other while others are too apart from each other.

```
Show[#, Graphics@
    Point@(Join @@ (PolygonCoordinates /@ #["BoundaryPolygons"]))] &@
 BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[
  Text[Style["b", FontFamily -> "Cambria"]], _Text, 
  MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 1}]
```

[image]

Another strange thing is that setting `MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 0.1}` leaves ranges in the boundary with no point at all.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

**Edit**

For the original code,we can subdivide the line to add some points.

```
polys = #["BoundaryPolygons"] &@
   BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[
    Text[Style["b", FontFamily -> "Cambria"]], _Text, 
    MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 1}];
δ = 1/4;
lines = MeshPrimitives[#, 1] & /@ polys;
Flatten[Map[
    Subdivide[Sequence @@ First@#, Ceiling[ArcLength@#/δ]] &, 
    lines, {2}], 1] // Map@Point // Graphics
```

[image]

- We can use `ExportString` to extract the boundary curves from the fonts.( we can read https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FilledCurve.html)

```
HighlightMesh[
 BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[
  ImportString[
    ExportString[Text[Style["b", FontFamily -> "Cambria"]], 
     "PDF"], {"PDF", "PageGraphics"}, "TextOutlines" -> True][[1, 1, 
    2]]], 0]
```

[image]

- `MaxCellMeasure -> .01`

```
HighlightMesh[
 BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[
  ImportString[
    ExportString[Text[Style["b", FontFamily -> "Cambria"]], 
     "PDF"], {"PDF", "PageGraphics"}, "TextOutlines" -> True][[1, 1, 
    2]], MaxCellMeasure -> .01], 0]
```

[image]

Comment: It is better many times... but still there is discrepancy at the same spots... look at small red circles in my OP, there are two pairs of points too close to each other... same spots here at upper left part of `b`. Why?

Comment: And also it is not clear to me why we have to use PDF in the process... and it does not work with all letters, for example letters `q` or `H` have some double points in their mesh.